# Angular2: Can I get a list of components loaded by the application?

Tags: angular

I want to get a list of loaded components for profiling.

I tried to do it on `bootstrap`, but I conclude that no API is provided.

```
bootstrap(MyApp, []).then((cmpRef) => {
  ...
});
```

Really is there no way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen anything like that.

If it is only about your custom components you can make them register themselves

```
constructor(componentRegistry:ComponentRegistry) {
  componentRegistry.add(this);
}
```